# Why does VS2013 compile a function-call into two instructions instead of one?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compilation, function-call

Here is a simple program:

```
void func()
{
    printf("hello");
}

int main()
{
    printf("%p",func);
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Stepping over the line `printf("%p",func)`, I get `00F811AE` printed on the console.

Disassembling the line `func()`, gives me `call _func (0F811AEh)` - so far so good.

But disassembling the contents of `func`, the first instruction appears at address `00F813C0`.

So I "went to see" what's on address `00F811AE`, and there I found `jmp func (0F813C0h)`.

To summarize this, it appears that the function-call is compiled as two instructions:

```
call _func (0F811AEh)
jmp   func (0F813C0h)
```

**Why does the VS2013 compiler use two instructions instead of just one?**

It appears that a single `jmp` would do the the job. I am asking even this because I have a feeling that the other compilers do it in a similar manner (depending on the underlying HW architecture of course).

Thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859188/in-visual-studio-debugmode-compiled-executable-jmp-to-function-body-instead-of) related ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but there must be a cast for `"%p"`:  `printf("%p", (void *)func);`

Comment: @AlterMann: You are right that "%p" is for object pointers and not function pointers. However, what you are suggesting also leads to undefined behaviour. See accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741683/how-to-format-a-function-pointer

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, true!

Comment: @quantdev: Thanks! Your link leads to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2485336/1382251, which in turn leads to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf%28VS.80%29.aspx, and there are some good explanations there on how to change it from two instructions to one instructions (if I understand correctly)... Will give it a try...

Comment: Do you disassemble the code with an external program?

Comment: @sharptooth: No, with the VS2013 debugger.

Comment: Good, that's the optimal way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Learn about "thunking": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk

One benefit with "thunking" in your example is that the rest of your code will always call **func**, but any function performing the same role could be injected into the call at address 0x00F811AE.

Try making **func** a **static** one and find out if anything changes.

Comment: +1 specifically, if `printf()` is loaded from a dll dynamically, then the address can be patched in at one place in memory and all the calls to it will find it from there....

Comment: barak manos: You're welcome.  Also worth considering is that the thunk might be dealing with calling convention differences, if it is indeed a thunk.

Comment: Also worth mentioning (according to links provided in some of the comments to my question), that you can reduce it from two instructions to one instruction through the linker-settings of your project.

Comment: so does this only happen when you link to dynamic RTL?

Comment: Matt McNabb: I don't think so.  This wouldn't be an example of thunking for an RTL function, but for barak manos' external-linkage function: func.  It could be more related to calling convention.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I have no idea what you mean by that. I have not linked to any DLL (besides what comes along in the VS-project's  default configuration).

Comment: OK. The other links suggest that it is to enable incremental linking (my understanding of which is that it's a technique to improve link times for large projects)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: So what you're saying is - improve linkage performance over runtime performance???

Comment: @barakmanos Yeah, it's useful for debugging but for a final release you would disable it

Comment: Yep, declaring the function `static` reduces it from two instructions to one instruction, which proves that it's a linkage issue, since `static` functions can be resolved before linkage (i.e., during compilation).