# Machine code address of call function translates to another address when viewing in disassembly and actually being executed. Why?

Tags: memory, x86, memory-address, native-code, disassembly

I was playing with a shellcode example and put some code on the stack. Here is a relevant fragment from it, as seen in the memory view of VS2013:

```
Memory view:
0x0018FEB4  90 90 90 83 ec 28 eb 0b e8 66 2a 1a 75 50 e8 9d 80 18 75
```

Now, when I see the same code in the disassembly view, interpreted in x86 machine language, all goes as expected, except for the addresses( in little endian) I see for the call instructions (opcode E8):

```
Disassembly view:
0018FEB4  nop  
0018FEB5  nop  
0018FEB6  nop  
0018FEB7  sub         esp,28h  
0018FEBA  jmp         0018FEC7  
0018FEBC  call        75332927  
0018FEC1  push        eax  
0018FEC2  call        75317F64
```

If I change the view to disassembly with code bytes, I get the same type of delta between the address that I have written to memory and the address that gets called:

```
Disassembly view, with code bytes as well:
0018FEBC E8 66 2A 1A 75       call        75332927
```

I think I may be missing some big theoretical fact with this one, but could some one explain it to me? 
The addresses I wanted to call are specific function addresses from kernel32.dll, but I had to make some arithmetic on them to actually make the code execute and call the correct addresses.

Comment: Pretty unclear, I'd guess that you don't realize that the CALL instruction uses a *relative* offset.  0x18fec1 + 0x75a1a266 == 0x75332927

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I hadn't taken into account the offset relative to the next instruction which CALL uses!

Comment: check this question

[Address of function is not actual code address][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485336/address-of-function-is-not-actual-code-address